# Django how to add a pk to a request object?

Tags: python, django, request

I am struggling in my TDD to add a pk inside a request object in Django.

Here is my trial :

```
request             = HttpRequest()
request.method      = "GET"
request.GET         = request.GET.copy()
request.GET["pk"]   =  1
response            = info_station(request)
```

knowing that the info_Station take a pk as parameter :

```
def info_station(request, pk):
```

And my url file :

```
url(r'^info_station/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', views.info_station)
```

The error is :

```
info_station() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pk'
```

How can I add this 'pk' parameter into my request ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don’t have to set pk on the request. You should pass it to the view as a separate argument, for example:

```
request = HttpRequest()
request.method = "GET"
response = info_station(request, pk=1)
```

You may find [`RequestFactory`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/advanced/#the-request-factory) useful for creating request objects in unit tests:

```
from django.test import RequestFactory
factory = RequestFactory()
request = self.factory.get('/info_station/1')
response = info_station(request, pk=1)
```

Or you may find it even easier to use the [test client](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/tools/#overview-and-a-quick-example):

```
from django.test import Client
client = Client()
response = client.get('/info_station/1')
```